# A joint probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, marginal-probability

> Consider the joint probability density function
>   $$
> f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
> \frac1y,& 0<x<y, \ \ 0<y<1\\
> 0,& \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   (a) Find the marginal probability density function of $Y$ and identify its distribution.
>
> (b) Find the conditional probability density function of $X$ given $Y=y$ and hence find the mean and variance of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$.

I've attempted part a of the question, but I think I’ve done it wrong so I’m getting errors in part b.
So far, I have integrated the function with respect to $x$ to get $f_y(y)= \frac{x}{y}=1$ using the limits $y$ and $0$. I am unsure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Note that $f_Y$ should not be a function of $x$.

Comment: @Math1000 could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Math1000 Thankyou for the help, to piggybank on the question, to find the expected value, i would have to integrate with regards to y then regards to x, would both limits be 0 and 1?

Comment: @hadams12 You should accept answers if the answers helps.

Answer (score 1):

To find the marginal density of $Y$, we integrate $f_{X,Y}$ over all possible values of $x$:
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_0^y \frac1y\ \mathsf dx = \mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(y).
$$
This is just the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

The conditional density of $X$ given $y=y$ is found by dividing the joint density by the marginal density of $Y$:

$$
f_{X\mid Y=y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = f_{X,Y}(x,y),\ 0<y<1.
$$
Hence the mean of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$ is
$$
\int_0^y \frac xy\ \mathsf dx = \frac y2
$$
and the variance of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$ is
$$
\int_0^y \frac{\left(x-\frac y2\right)^2}y\ \mathsf dx = \frac{y^2}{12}.
$$